# Does Pig rerun previous statements with a new DUMP statement?

Tags: apache-pig

Supposed I run the following statements one at a time in Pig Grunt:

```
A = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a1:int, a2:int, a3:float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE a1+a2 AS b1, a3 AS b2;
DUMP B;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE b1*b2 AS c1;
DUMP C;
```

When I execute `DUMP C`, does it only execute the new statement or will it execute all 3 statements?

Comment: You should give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dump is mainly to see what results your PIG script produces, you can use it to debug your script.

While executing the script it searches for the immediate Alias mentioned, in your case its 'C'. the alias usage is back traced and the execution starts from the parent itself.

Here it would be first A, then B and finally C and then you see the results. So to bring the results of alias C, it needs to check Alias B and for that it needs Alias A first and so the execution goes on, 'Dump B' will not get executed though as it does not change or alter the Alias B in any way (it just posts the result of alias B.)

Comment: I see. So, it will execute the needed statements and ignore the rest.